# Different computers can have session data (stored from SQL Server) displayed after each user finishes filling in the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I am creating a web application using ASP.NET C# Web forms. I created the sessions to store the data in SQL Server. I use sessionState to set the timeout for the sessions. Below is what I have:

`<sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
               sqlConnectionString="Data Source = server_name; Initial Catalog = database_name; User ID = username; Password = pwd;" 
               allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" 
               cookieless="false" 
               regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
               timeout="1440" />`

I want the users who use their own computers from different places can retrieve the session data stored in SQL Server so that they can keep entering the data to complete the web forms from the previous users' entered data.

I tried a persistent session as below on my computer:

```
protected void Application_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionIdTemp"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] == null)
            Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionIdTemp"].Value));
        else
            Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionIdTemp"].Value;
    }
}

protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpModuleCollectio

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionIdTemp", Session.SessionID);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Session.Timeout);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

But the other users won't have the session data unless they complete the web forms using my computer. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

> I want the users who use their own computers from different places can
>   retrieve the session data stored in SQL Server so that they can keep
>   entering the data to complete the web forms from the previous users'
>   entered data.

The main reason of storing Session State in SQL Server (or State server) is for load balancing. Idea is ***multiple Web Servers shares the same session state***.

What you are trying to do is - ***Multiple Computers (or Browsers) share the same session state***? It is not how session state works.

By default, Session State expires in 20 minutes. So even if you can retrieve session id from cookie, that session becomes invalid after 20 minutes.

In addition, ***you should not create a cookie and retrieve the previous data based on the cookie.*** It will become a big security hole, if a user enters data in public computer (such as library).

If you want user to continue where s/he left off. ***You need to ask user to login.*** Then ties the user with a temporary table in database.

Comment: I am thinking about creating the table(s) in tempdb to store the data, but I have the problem with losing the table(s) when I exit SQL Server. Can we set the expired date and time for the table(s) in tempdb? How can we do that? Thanks.

Comment: You should create a real table to persist the data. Then run a scheduler to clear abandoned records at certain time frame. For example, [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)